# How to sort a single String in Alphabetic Order with only util.Scanner package in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, alphabetical, anagram

Only the `import java.util.Scanner` package is allowed.

How to Sort a Single String (it's characters) in Alphabetic order in Java?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        int i,j,k,l;
        char temp;
        // Complete the function
         a = a.toLowerCase();
         b = b.toLowerCase();
         char [] ca =a.toCharArray();
         char [] cb = b.toCharArray();
         for(i=0;i<=a.length()-1;i++){
            for(j=i+1;j<=a.length()-1;j++){
                if(ca[i]>ca[j]){
                    temp = ca[i];
                    ca[i]=ca[j];
                    ca[j]=temp;
                }
            }
         }
         for(k=0;k<=b.length()-1;k++){
             for(l=k+1;l<=b.length()-1;l++){
                if(cb[k]>cb[l]){
                    temp = cb[k];
                    cb[k]=cb[l];
                    cb[l]=temp;
                }
             }
         }
          a = String.valueOf(ca);
          b = String.valueOf(cb);
         if(a.equals(b)){
             return true;
         }
         else{
             return false;
         }         

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = scan.next();
        String b = scan.next();
        scan.close();
        boolean ret = isAnagram(a, b);
        System.out.println( (ret) ? "Anagrams" : "Not Anagrams" );
    }
}
```

This is my code. I tried this. but this sorting does'nt work. it's actually program for Anagram.

Comment: Basically this means you have to do it on your own without using library methods. Give it a try!

Comment: if you've tried and are stuck, show your code and we can help explain where the problem is. This is not a place to just ask for solutions though

Comment: i tried but i could'nt find out. could anyone help? i'm beginner to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you wanted to exchange elements i and j here:

```
        if(ca[i]>ca[j]){
            temp = ca[0];
            ca[0]=ca[1];
            ca[1]=temp;
        }
```

but instead you exchange elements 0 and 1.

Comment: yes! ur right :) it works fine now. i got the output. Thanks :p it's a silly mistake though

Answer (score 0):

Install java 1.8 and use its outstanding feature as shown in the below code.

```
    Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string:" );
    String data  = scanner.next();

    data.chars().sorted().forEach( character -> { System.out.print((char)character); }
```

( This uses only Scanner import and nothing else )

Comment: Nah, you can do that in Java 7 too. i got the ouput. i editted the code. see how it works!!